# epuck2_robot_0-1 process has died [pid 7332, exit code 1, cmd ~/epuck2_ws/devel/lib/epuck_driver_cpp/epuck_driver_cpp

Tags: rviz, ros-noetic, ros1

I installed Ubuntu 20.04-LST, started "roscore", and then executed

```
roslaunch epuck_driver_cpp epuck2_controller.launch epuck2_address:='192.168.11.108'
```

However, it resulted in an error

```
[epuck2_robot_0-1] process has died [pid 7332, exit code 1, cmd /home/bcfy/epuck2_ws/devel/lib/epuck_driver_cpp/epuck_driver_cpp
```

The IP address of the robot is correct. What could be the reason?
I downloaded epuck_driver_cpp from https://github.com/gctronic/epuck_driver_cpp.